# In Rails 5, how do I iterate over an active record set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I'm having trouble iterating over a set of active records.  I access them like so

```
 priority_countries_ids = Country.where(:iso=>priority_countries).all
priority_countries_ids.each do |pc|
```

but on the "each" line, I'm getting the error

```
can't quote Array
```

There is no other information.  I don't know how else to troubleshoot this and simply want to iterate over each result from my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
priority_countries: [["US", "United States"], ["CA", "Canada"]]
```

The problem is because your priority_countries is not a 1D Array.(http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches)

`priority_countries_ids = Country.where(:iso=>priority_countries.flatten).all` // Converting priority_countries to 1D using flatten.

Hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you print priority_countries ? Are you sure it's an array of values ? 
try

```
Country.where(:iso=>priority_countries.to_a).all
```

Comment: Tnis used to wokr in Rails 4, but trying your suggestion gives me the same error.  When I add 'puts "priority countries: #{priority_countries} class: #{priority_countries.class}"' right before the problematic statement, it prints out, "priority countries: [["US", "United States"], ["CA", "Canada"]] class: Array"

Comment: what is the type of country.iso ? is it a string or an array?

Comment: It is a string (the actual Postgres 9.5 column type is "character varying")